# Type safety in string arguments

Tags: c#, strong-typing

My specific question is about ASP.NET MVC but I am sure that the answers can be applied outside ASP.NET.

How do you deal with functions that accept string arguments but still you want type safety?

In ASP.NET, the extension method Html.ActionLink has two arguments of type string: `string linkText, string actionName`. The first argument is a text that can be loaded from a resource but the second argument is the name of a method that exists in code.

One option would be to create a class with constant strings so instead of writing

```
 Html.ActionLink("Blah blah", "MyAction");
```

one could write:

```
Html.ActionLine("Blah blah", StrongType.MyAction);
```

Where `MyAction` is a const string in a class called `StrongType`. However, this becomes a pain to manage when the number of methods and other objects that can be passed as arguments increases.

A second option would be to load somehow the name of the function using Reflection but this seems too expensive.

Is there a better way of doing it? How do you make sure that you don't have typos in string arguments like the ones mentioned before?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the ActionLink extension method that allows you to avoid the use of these magic string.

```
<%= Html.ActionLink<BlahController>(c => c.MyAction(), "Blah blah");
```

You'll need to reference `Microsoft.Web.Mvc` which is part of ASP.NET MVC 3 Futures and available at http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/58781.

Comment: Where is this overload of `ActionLink` defined?   I do not see it in ASP.NET/MVC 3.

Comment: @Lester, what version?  And what class is it defined in?  It is not present in the release version of ASP.NET/MVC 3.

Comment: @Kirk Woll: are you sure you're looking at Microsoft.Web.Mvc and not System.Web.Mvc? I've just double checked and it's present in the ASP.NET MVC 3 Futures assembly at http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/58781

Comment: Ah, thank you!  IMO, it is a **crucial** piece of information that should have been mentioned that your suggestion is non-standard and not available without a separate download.  But +1.

Comment: Actually, I learned something new too. I didn't realize it was in the Futures assembly since I've been using S#arp Architecture framework which already included it.

Answer (score 1):

I think Lester's answer is appropriate for this specific case.  But in the more general situation, you really need to define the constants and use them.  Yes, it is a pain, but you can set up a *lot* of constants in the time you save not having to track down a bug caused by giving an argument "Yellow" when you meant "yellow".

Now, if you are person designing the method being called, don't make it a string argument when you really have a set of constant values it will accept.  Make it an enum.

Comment: I disagree.  It think there are better ways to solve this problem then introducing this *massive* maintenance overhead.

Comment: @Kirk Woll: I'd like to see some of these "better ways"

Comment: @Neil, an extension method like what Lester described is certainly better.  Using ReSharper to statically detect these errors is certainly better.  etc.

Comment: @Kirk Woll:  Unless we are picturing pretty different circumstances, I don't really understand how the overhead is so massive.  You need to define a helper class and a number of constants.  (You can even skip the helper class if everything is in the same class.)  Once you've done that, the compiler becomes your good friend and helps you avoid serious errors.  Like I stated in my answer, just avoiding one session trying to track down a mis-typed string would likely pay back many times the effort of setting up the constants

Comment: Every time you add a new action, you have to add a new entry wherever you are storing your constants.  That is an incredibly painful workflow.  It would be like adding a value to an enum every time you add a property to a class.  That would really take the wind out of my sails.